# Is there a way to write clean swiper js props in react?

Tags: reactjs, swiper.js

I'm trying to make the code like this if it's possible

like framer motion varinats:

```
export default function Carousel() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(null);

  const swiper_varinats = {
    allowTouchMove: false,
    slidesPerView: 2,
    loop: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    onTransitionStart: (e) => setIndex(e.realIndex),
  };

  return (
      <Swiper varinats={swiper_varinats}>
        <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the `swiper_variants` object into the `Swiper` component.

```
export default function Carousel() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(null);

  const swiper_variants = {
    allowTouchMove: false,
    slidesPerView: 2,
    loop: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    onTransitionStart: (e) => setIndex(e.realIndex),
  };

  return (
      <Swiper {...swiper_variants}>
        <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
  );
}
```

Doing this will take the properties you defined in your `swiper_variants` object, and apply them to your `Swiper` component. It's the equivalent of doing this:

```
export default function Carousel() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(null);

  const swiper_variants = {
    allowTouchMove: false,
    slidesPerView: 2,
    loop: true,
    centeredSlides: true,
    onTransitionStart: (e) => setIndex(e.realIndex),
  };

  return (
      <Swiper 
        allowTouchMove={swiper_variants.allowTouchMove}
        slidesPerView={swiper_variants.slidesPerView}
        loop={swiper_variants.loop}
        centeredSlides={swiper_variants.centeredSlides}
        onTransitionStart={swiper_variants.onTransitionStart}
      >
        <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
        <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
      </Swiper>
  );
}
```

Here is a [nice article](https://scrimba.com/articles/react-spread-operator/) on using the spread operator in React.

A really cool thing about using the spread operator to pass props into a React component is that it opens you up to a simple way of `overwriting` (or merging) props from your original object with some other config.

Checkout this example

```
// Set up some default config for your component
const defaultConfig = {
  allowTouchMove: false,
  slidesPerView: 2,
  loop: true,
  centeredSlides: true,
};


/** 
 * Optionally pass in swiperConfig to override and extend
 * the defaultConfig object
 */
export default function Carousel({ swiperConfig = {} }) {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(null);

  return (
    <Swiper 
      // Spread in your defaultConfig
      { ...defaultConfig } 
      // Spread in your swiperConfig
      { ...swiperConfig }
      // Explicitly define callbacks if they interact with local state...
      onTransitionStart={(e) => {
        setIndex(e.realIndex)
        //... and invoke the callback from your config if it exists.
        swiperConfig.onTransitionStart?.(e);
      }}
    >
      <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>hi</SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
  );
}
```

*Note: If you haven't seen `?.` used before, checkout the docs for [`optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).*

You can use this example like so:

```
// A Carousel that only has the default props you wanted applied
<Carousel />

// A Carousel that overrides/extends your default Swiper props
<Carousel
  swiperConfig={{
    // override default allowTouchMove value
    allowTouchMove: true,
    
    // add in some new props for this specific Carousel/Swipper
    effect: 'coverflow',
    coverflowEffect: {
      rotate: 30,
      slideShadows: false,
    },
    
    // extend functionality for the onTransitionStart event
    onTransitionStart: (e) => console.log(e),
  }}
/>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: u just answerd my question and gave me a really big tip thank u sir